# Copy files such that individual files gets copied to the folder having file name as a string within complete folder name

Tags: linux, command-line, find, file-copy

I am using Cygwin as Linux shell, I have following contents in my current working directory:

Files :

```
Abc.dat 
123.dat 
456.dat
```

Directories:

```
W_Abc_w 
W_123_w 
W_456_w
```

Now I want to copy files as below:

```
Abc.dat -> W_Abc_w 
123.dat -> W_123_w 
456.dat -> W_456_w
```

How to achieve this in a single line linux command? 
I need a generic solution which can be used for similar cases in future...

Destination directory always exists, but number of characters in file name will vary. Destination directory name will always contain the file name of file to be copied along with other extra characters. 
Destination directory names have unique pattern eg. Abc_sa_file_name_1 second directory name will be Abc_sa_file_name_2. File names also has pattern e.g kim_1.  Kim_2 .
I will be moving or copying file kim_1 to Abc_sa_kim_1_1. I wish to operate complete pattern in one command.

Comment: In a single command you mean without for loop?

Comment: Right, may be using system variables

Comment: That one very specific result, or by following some pattern (that you should describe)?

Comment: Using the patterns and variables.

Comment: Do your filenames always match ???.dat? Will the destination directories always exist?

Comment: Destination directory always exists, but number of characters in file name will vary. Destination directory name will always contain the file name of file to be copied along with other extra characters.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/553216/edit) ... thank you!

Comment: Show examples of filenames with a different number of characters, along with its destination directory.  Keep others from assuming what I did! :)

Comment: Destination directory always exists, but number of characters in file name will vary. Destination directory name will always contain the file name of file to be copied along with other extra characters. Destination directory names have unique pattern eg. Abc_sa_<file name>_1     second directory name will be Abc_sa_<file name>_2.             File names also has pattern e.g kim_1.  Kim_2 .                       I will be moving or copying kim_1 to Abc_sa_kim_1_1.

Comment: How one can perform this operation with <find> and <-exec> command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one command (line):

```
cp Abc.dat W_Abc_w/; cp 123.dat W_123_w/; cp 456.dat W_456_w/
```

The trailing slashes are not required, but a habit to indicate that the intention is to put the file into a destination *directory* not as a new *file*.

As a generic loop with a pattern:

```
for f in ???.dat
do
  [ -d W_"${f%.dat}"_w ] && cp -- "$f" W_"${f%.dat}"_w
done
```

This picks up every filename that has three characters followed by `.dat` and copies them into the correspondingly-named directory, if that directory already exists. The filename expansion inside the `cp` command strips off the trailing `.dat`.

If you were interested in a command-line approach that does not use a loop -- but also *moves* the files instead of *copies* them -- you could use zsh:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(???).dat' 'W_$1_w'
```

Comment: Last one seems good, I will try it and let you know what happened! Thanks

Comment: @VikramTidake I believe that `mmv` is available for Cygwin, providing shell-independent functionality similar to `zmv` if you prefer ex. `mmv '???.dat' 'W_#1#2#3_w/'` - it has a `-c` option (and possibly a `mcp` binary) to copy rather than move.

Comment: How one can perform this operation with <find> command?

Comment: Vikram, if your requirement is to use "find", please make that explicit in your question. I will re-add the "find" tag. Thank you.